# Use of final when referencing an Object type

Tags: java, final

```
private final  List<KeyListener> keyListeners= new CopyOnWriteArrayList<KeyListener>();

public void addKeyListener(KeyListener keyListener){
  keyListeners.add(keyListener);
}
```

In the above code I declare keyListeners to be final and also it is thread-safe . I assume by final I mean that the state of the listener can not change after construction . But am I not doing the same in the addKeyListener() method ? Why does the compiler doesn't give me an warning ?  What am I missing here ?

Comment: More on final: [Java Practices - Use final liberally](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=23 "Java Practices - Use final liberally")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final keyword is used to tell that the variable may only be assigned to once. But you can call method on it even if it "change" object properties.

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) :

> Once a final variable has been assigned, it always contains the same value. If a final variable holds a reference to an object, then the state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the variable will always refer to the same object.

Comment: +1 for putting the link to JLS. This answers exactly what I wanted to learn .

Comment: @Subhra You're welcome, JLS often provides all the informations you need to know about Java!

Answer (score 5):

Adding the `final` keyword means that `keyListeners` will point to the same `CopyOnWriteArrayList` throughout the entire program. It would be illegal to do:

```
keyListeners = null
```

However, methods of `keyListeners` can still be called freely. Whether they affect the underlying data structure is not something the compiler cares about.

---

```
class Foo {
    public int bar = 1;

    public static void test() {
       final Foo x = new Foo();

       //This is perfectly legal:
       x.bar = 2;

       //This is not:
       x = new Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: @eric how is the use of 'final ' different when added to a primitive type like int and when added to a reference type like in this case ? I thought 'final' fields are kind of constant in that they can never change their state .

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: From the question, it appears that the OP doesn't want immutability, but is just wondering why the code above works

Comment: @Subra: They can change state, just not value. Once a final field is set, it cannot be changed to a new value. However, if the value is an object, it's fields can be changed freely.

Comment: @Eric +1 for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Just because final refere to internal address of keyListeners and not to th List itself.